# Running Grunt tasks in blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I have 5 tasks to run. Grunt's task limit is set to 10. I want to run those tasks in a block of two. I meant, run 2 tasks, wait for them to complete, then run other two. How can I do that? I tried to use queue, but did not work

Comment: Grunt doesn't have a *"task limit"*. Could you provide some of the code you tried to give more insight into what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: grunt.registerTask("test", ["testBlock"]) for 5 times. Instead, I want to run them in a block of 2 at the interval of 5 minutes

Comment: Could you update your question with a longer description / code examples of what you're trying to accomplish? At the moment your question is very vague and makes it very hard to give an answer. Especially useful if you could provide a real world example.

Comment: I found a solution: we can create blocks within a grunt file, and link it to a main script. Thanks, anyway!